# What is the most efficient way to compute elementary symmetric functions?

Tags: combinatorics, computational-complexity, symmetric-polynomials

Certainly straightforward substitution into
$$
e_k(x_1,...,x_n)=\sum_{\substack{s\,\subseteq\,\{1,...,n\}\\\text{$s$ has $k$ elements}}}\prod_{i\in s}x_i
$$
is very inefficient way to compute values of symmetric functions on some concrete numbers $x_i$: the number $\binom nk$ of summands grows very rapidly.

Much more efficient is to first compute the power sums
$$
p_j(x_1,...,x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^j
$$
and then use [the formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Expressing_elementary_symmetric_polynomials_in_terms_of_power_sums)
$$
e_k(x_1,...,x_n) = (-1)^k  \sum_{\substack{m_1 + 2m_2 + \cdots\, =\, k \\ m_1, m_2,\,\cdots\, \geqslant\, 0}} \frac{(-p_1)^{m_1}}{1^{m_1}m_1!}\frac{(-p_2)^{m_2}}{2^{m_2}m_2!}\cdots 
$$
Still there are as many summands as there are partitions of $k$.

Probably even more efficient are the Newton recurrent formulas
$$
e_k(x_1,...,x_n)=\frac1k(p_1e_{k-1}-p_2e_{k-2}+\cdots\pm p_{k-1}e_1\mp p_k),
$$
but since this requires computation of all the previous $e$'s, here I am not sure anymore whether this is more efficient than the previous one.

Is it? And are there any even more efficient ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two efficient algorithms for computing ESFs, the sum and the difference algorithm. For review of both of these see these two papers:

`@article{liou1994,
    Author = {Liou, Michelle},
    Journal = {Applied Psychological Measurement},
    Number = {1},
    Pages = {53--62},
    Publisher = {Sage Publications Sage CA: Thousand Oaks, CA},
    Title = {More on the computation of higher-order derivatives of the elementary symmetric functions in the Rasch model},
    Volume = {18},
    Year = {1994}}`

`@article{baker1996,
    Author = {Baker, Frank B and Harwell, Michael R},
    Journal = {Applied Psychological Measurement},
    Number = {2},
    Pages = {169--192},
    Publisher = {Sage Publications Sage CA: Thousand Oaks, CA},
    Title = {Computing elementary symmetric functions and their derivatives: A didactic},
    Volume = {20},
    Year = {1996}}`

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much!